# Current sense pin detect too quickly (Flyback)

Tags: flyback, current-sensing

Here is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3hwfD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is two problems:

1. Firstly, the sense circuit don't open the mosfet at 1V, yet the zener at the V+ in the amp op have a zener of 1v that limit the threshold to 1V (in the pwm circuit).

2)If I estimate the current slope E/L, I'm supposed to reach the 1a current in 2us, I don't understand why I reach 1a in 100ns, (maybe the current stuck in th drain capacitor increase the slope)
E=350 and Lp=750uH
Filtering my signal doesn't change anything.

Here is my curves picture, the sense current in yellow, and Vds in blue.
[image]

PWM:https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/UC3844B_D-2320086.pdf
SMPS:https://docs.rs-online.com/696a/0900766b80107114.pdf

Comment: Maybe you have your dots on the proper circuit implementation the opposite of what the circuit correctly suggests? It's a common error to make.

Comment: You mean dots on inductance ? In the true circuit the primary dot is on the drain mosfet and the auxiliary dot is at the ground.

Comment: I'm talking about primary to secondary dots here.

Comment: I usually respected the circuit with the smps datasheet, I don't figure out why it can affect my circuit, the primary dot is on the drain mosfet, this configuration can be the problem ? I modified the circuit xith the true representation of my circuit

Comment: But how about the transformer primary to secondary polarity, i.e. dot convention?

Comment: Thank you I think I have reversed output diode in the wrong direction, I'm used to work with primary dot on the top, not on the drain of the NMOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concentrate on what I'm telling you. This is important.

This is a flyback converter design and, when the MOSFET activates, current is drawn into the primary winding at a certain rate determined by primary inductance and input DC supply voltage. If the secondary winding does not appear to be open circuit when this happens, the whole idea of it being a flyback converter fails. The secondary circuit is made to be open circuit during the primary charge sequence by both the secondary diode direction and the effective winding dots between primary and secondary. If either the diode is the wrong way round or the dots are not as they should be then it won't behave as a flyback converter.

What you appear to be indicating in comments leads me to believe that you have got this muddled up and the converter will not behave as a flyback converter. It also appears to be incorrect in your updated circuit. In other words the secondary diode conducts when the primary MOSFET activates and this is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand clearly this part, when the primary current is flowing, current on secondary isn't flowing because secondary diode is blocked, I think I have to revise this notion of dot in SMPS, I will come back to give you my results. thanks

Comment: Good man and best of luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

@Andy aka respond to my question but I want show my result.
[image]

Indeed I have put my diode on the wrong direction.
We can calculate the slope = 357142, this value is very close to E/L.
Moreover the current sense detection open the circuit to 1V.
(I have already put RC filter for sensing detection but spikes doesn't disappear)
Small detail, I changed snubber value to 25nF and 7k resistor.
Thanks.

Comment: Blue waveform looks like the secondary voltage to me. If so, then bang on.

Comment: I say that because it goes negative when the MOSFET is on. That's how I read it anyway.

Comment: No it is unfortunately  Vds,  in theory Vds can't be below 0. It's a problem ?.

Comment: It can't be below the input supply. Maybe your probing is a little wrong or maybe it is something else.

Comment: Thanks, I will focus on that problem